# assgning several tag for a blog post implementaion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm going to make user able to assign several tag for blog post(like what stackoverflow do about tag and question), this is my post model

```
 public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the tag

```
public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string TagSlug { get; set; }

    }
```

and when I want to create a post I simply get list of all tags in a dropdownlist and get it's Id in post action and blah blah! So to make it possible to assign several tags for a post how should change my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to establish a Many:Many relationship with your `Posts` and `Tags`, since a `Post` can have many `Tags`, and a `Tag` will be applied to many `Posts`.

That means you'll at least want to store a collection of the associated `Tags` on your the `Post` object. Optionally, you may want to store a collection of associated `Posts` on your `Tag` object as well.

So, changing your single `Tag` to a collection:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string TagSlug { get; set; }

    // Navigation property (optional)
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

If you're doing code first development, Entity Framework should be able to sort out your database structure and tables using the default conventions/mappings.

If you already have an existing database, you may have to perform some explicit mapping, e.g.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasMany(t => t.Tags)
                .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
                .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("PostId")
                           .MapRightKey("TagId")
                           .ToTable("PostTags"));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've released my web site and now wanna to use code first migration, is it possible to use you solution with EF code first migration??

Comment: Hi, although I haven't actually used Code First Migrations, it looks like it should be fairly straightforward. The Code First Migrations section in the Entity Framework documentation has some good tutorials: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907 (Code First Migrations are about half way down the page).